# Windows 10 nested virtualization on AMD CPU

Tags: windows, virtualization, amd-processor

I am working on a Software company, mainly developing on Linux. For Windows development we have couple of machines that are shared. However, a new project came up, and we need more resources on Windows. So we decided to use KVM/VFIO to run Windows in Virtual Machines, instead of buying more PCs.

Everything worked fine, until we needed to use Nested Virtualization, for several tasks. It works, but the performance is very bad, crippling down to 20% of bare-metal.

After a little googling I found out that this happens only to AMD processors running Windows 10. Microsoft never deployed their dev branch where optimizations for AMD processors were implemented. Intel+W10, or AMD+W11, work fine.

Since the latest article was over 2 years ago, I cannot trust that info 100%. So before I start re-installing Windows and software packages on all our W10 VMs, does anybody know if this is true? We are running 21H1 versions, and there is 22H2 available. Will this work or my only option is upgrade to W11 (which include re-installing as TPM/Secure-boot is not enabled to these VMs) ?

Answer (score 0):

Been trying all day to make it work with 22H2, but I have even more issues than before. Random crashes, DirectX errors, lag, even complete freezes.

So, my personal opinion is that M$ ignored AMD users for nested virtualization on Windows 10 and we are forced to upgrade to Windows 11, regardless of the cost for a company to buy all these licenses.